# Jsch error return codes not consistent

Tags: java, ssh

I am using the nice http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ library - however when I run some commands, I see that jsch returns a getExitStatus of -1, from time to time, even though the script ran fine (when I run it by hand it is consistently a successful 0 exit code). Any ideas?

(seems to happen to a wide variety of commands)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gave up on Jsch - and its incredibly unhelpful API and switched to:

http://www.cleondris.ch/opensource/ssh2/

(Ganymede SSH2). 
I do a LOT with ssh in the JVM and over months of 24 hour usage ganymede has proven far more reliable. And more pleasant. My main remaining gripe is around being apparently unable to set timeouts for SCP.

Comment: I have also been burned by JSch and it's awful api and their docs: "... and only after the channel was closed (more exactly, just before the channel is closed)."

Answer (score 3):

I suffered the same issue and then came across this in the Jsch changelog (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ChangeLog):

> - feature: added 'Channel.isClosed()'. Channel.getExitStatus() should be
>      invoked after Channel.isClosed()==true.

So knocked this up:  Needs to be called *before* channel.disconnect(), else still get -1 issue:

```
private static void waitForChannelClosure(ChannelExec ce, long maxwaitMs) {

    log.info("waitForChannelClosure >>>");
    final long until = System.currentTimeMillis() + maxwaitMs;

    try {
        while (!ce.isClosed() && System.currentTimeMillis() < until) { 
            log.info("SFTP channel not closed .. waiting");
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted", e);
    }

    if (!ce.isClosed()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Channel not closed in timely manner!");
    }

};
```

Comment: Good to know ! but probably not switching back. There are some other options out there now (checkout jclouds for them)