# Wait for JSch command to execute instead of hard coding a fixed time to wait for

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
channel.connect();
while (channel.getExitStatus() == -1){
   try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}   
channel.disconnect();
```

In the code above we add line **`Thread.sleep(1000);`** to give the system enough time, to execute the command. However when I change the time gap from **1000 ms** to **200 ms**, the command doesn't execute.

Also in some slow servers, the command may not execute for the specified time gap of **1000 ms** too. Is there any other dynamic way to wait for the command to execute completely before the next starts executing instead of hard coding the value, *especially required while automating*?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154940/jsch-error-return-codes-not-consistent

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop reading chunks of the response until `channel.isClosed()` returns true.

At that point you can call `channel.getExitStatus()` to get the process exit code and then close the channel.

If you don't want to burn CPU cycles while looping to read the response bytes, put a `Thread.sleep(100)` between each read.